# FIRApp.configure() creating a memory leak IOS

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, firebase, cocoapods

I've been debugging my application which uses Firebase for memory leaks, and after some time digging into my code I've found that the actual problem is the `FIRApp.configure()` it inside my `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)` in AppDelegate.

As far as I know everything is configured in the right way, I'm using cocoa pods for installing and updating firebase. I'm also modifying my statusBar inside my AppDelegate the code is as follows:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    setStatusBarBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 231/250, green: 97/250, blue: 44/250, alpha: 1.0))

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true


}

var window: UIWindow?

override init() {
}

func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {

    guard  let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")?.valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView else {
        return
    }

    statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}
```

I'm also showing the instruments tool to show more details on the leak:

[image: The CFNetwork is the responsible library]

And I'm sure it's the `FIRApp.configure()` because I removed it for testing and there were no leaks.

Hope anyone has an idea on how to fix this leak, thank you.

Comment: did you get any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. After some digging, it seems like Firebase Analytics is the one causing the leak.

Here is what I did:

- set `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED` to `NO`
- `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED` to `YES` in `GoogleServiceIn-info.plist`.

At least this works for me. For those who rely on firebase analytics this definitely is a bug.

Comment: I'm no longer using Firebase for my app, so this was kind of late hahaha anyways thank you, I solved the problem in a similar way, hope they fix this issue soon.

Comment: Did you guys filled a bug report?

Comment: Can you point out which class or method caused the memory leak? I couldn't see it from the screenshot above. Mentioning "firebase analytics definitely is a bug" is not very helpful here.